# Importing Arduino byte data into Python3 using readline(). Want to assign data to variable names

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print (data)   #displays b'10.1,20.2,30.3 \r\n'
    data = a, b, c  
    print (a)   #get error msg, name 'a' not defined. I want a=10.1
```

Comment: Do you mean `a, b, c = data`? That won't do what you want still, but variables are declared on the left of `=`.

Comment: change `data = a, b, c` to `a, b, c = [int(x) for x in  data.decode().rstrip().split(",")]`

Comment: float ----> change to `a, b, c = [float(x) for x in data.decode().rstrip().split(",")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    data = data.strip().decode('utf-8') # to decode byte to unicode
    data = data.split(',') # you get something like ['10.1', '20.2', '30.3']
    a, b, c = [float(i) for i in data] # to transform to [10.1, 20.2, 30.3]
    print(a) # display 10.1
    print(b) # display 20.2
    print(c) # display 30.2
```

> **Update:** To get a `float`number, you just have to replace the function `int()` by the function `float()`

**Update:** Here is a new version of the code without the list-comprehensions syntax.

```
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    data = data.strip().decode('utf-8') # to decode byte to unicode
    data = data.split(',') # you get something like ['10.1', '20.2', '30.3']
    a = float(data[0]) # transform '10.1' to 10.1
    b = float(data[1]) # transform '20.2' to 20.2
    c = float(data[2]) # transform '30.3' to 30.3
    print(a) # display 10.1
    print(b) # display 20.2
    print(c) # display 30.2
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did not make it clear that the data are float data coded in bytes.

Comment: Okay. I updated the code. Don't forget to accept the result if your problem is solved.

Comment: I'm an 83 year old just learning programming. Don't know how to use stackoverflow. Need tutorial.

Comment: Okay. Is my answer solved your problem ? If **yes**, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in...

Comment: This, float x, solved the problem. Thank you very much!!

Comment: How do I close the posting? The question is solved.

Comment: Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in...

Comment: I still don't understand the statement: [float(i) for i in data]

Comment: `[float(i) for i in data]` is a **list comprehensions** synthax. I have just created a list that contains the **float values** of the `data` items. To know more about the list comprehension, check this link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: I updated the code, so you have another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. I had not heard of "list comprehensions". Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Oops, missed the point. a=float(data)[0] IS more readable than the list comprehensions. Thanks again!